# How to combine certificate with key and output pem file?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, webrtc, x509certificate, kurento

I have configured **kurento media server**, but for the SSL part it requires to have cert+key in pem format and also password. The issue is i have

```
 1. ca_bundle.crt
 2. certificate.crt
 3. private_key.key
```

Now how can i convert these to a valid cert+key.pem so that kurento media server can access it?

I had converted certificate.crt only to certificate.pem using openssl tool `openssl x509 -in cert.crt -out cert.pem`

But still its not working out. I have followed kurento guide to generate a self signed certificate it works, but yes there's not a green seal there so for that i bought a certificate online but cannot seem to get it working. Here is the guide for self signed certificate for kurento. [Guide for certificate](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.14.0/features/security.html#securing-kurento-media-server)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in cert.crt -out cert.pem -text
```